Limitations on Bulk Email Sending with Content Hub SDK
Is there a limit to the number of emails you can send in bulk using the Content Hub web client SDK with mclient.Notifications.SendEmailNotificationAsync()?
I am trying to send notification email to around 1400 Content Hub users. I am not getting any errors, but the emails are not being sent.

I created a Sitecore ticket for this issue, and after many conversations and troubleshooting, they identified it as a defect in the Content Hub product. However, they cannot provide a timeline for when the fix will be implemented and made available (Reference number: MONE-46375).
In the meantime, they provided a workaround. They recommend using the MailRequestById method and specifying the IDs of the user entities when creating the mail request. I was previously using MailRequestByUsername and passing the usernames, which caused the issue when creating mail requests.
Old Code:
var notificationRequest = new MailRequestByUsername {
    MailTemplateName = "EmailTemplatename",
    Recipients = new List<string> { "username1", "username2" } };

Recommended Code:
var notificationRequest = new MailRequestById
{
    MailTemplateName = "EmailTemplatename",
    Recipients = new List<long> { userEntityId1, userEntityId2 }
};

